# Is it possible to configure Kafka to not delete unread messages?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, apache-kafka-streams

I am completely aware that Kafka is a log and act as dumb pipes. But in our application we have some "compliance topics", where we need to ensure that all messages inside were read.

As Kafka internally handles offsets for all consumers (and hence it is possible to monitor consumer lag), I was wondering, if it's possible to set `log.retention=25GB`, but do not override messages, which were not read by anyone, rather throw a producer exception (as if we set `log.retention=1week` and HDD was full).

If it is not possible to configure this on Kafka level, is there any practical way how to implement this logic on kafka-producer or kafka-streams, so it fails in case of a "full unread log"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot configure Kafka to keep unread messages. However, you can increase the retention time/space and delete data manually using the new "purge data" API.

See https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-107%3A+Add+deleteRecordsBefore%28%29+API+in+AdminClient for details.